# GitLab: Accidentally changed permission from owner to master

Tags: permissions, gitlab

I accidentally changed my permission of my own project from owner to master. Is there any way to change it back to owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [Project users](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/add-user/add-user.html) documentation clearly states that you need owner right to manage users, I would fall back to asking an admin of the GitLab instance, in order to restore your initial permission.

Note that this should not be possible with a [recent enough GitLab (8.2.0+)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/CHANGELOG):

> Prevent the last owner of a group from being able to delete themselves by 'adding' themselves as a master.